# PHP Contact Form Issue (redirecting)

Tags: php

I am trying to set my PHP contact formso that when you click "SEND" it says thank you and redirects you to the home page. This is my script for the php and html. I know its just a few lines need adjusting, but not sure exactly how. I uploaded the mail.php file into my website directory.

```
  <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "horgantm@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader))

    { 
        header("Location: http://www.darthvixcustomsabers.com/index.html");
        exit;   
    }
    else
    {
        die("Error!");
    }
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";

?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> DV Custom Sabers </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/kotorsale.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


</head>
<div class="header"><a href="index.html">Darthvix Custom Sabers</a></div>

<div class="header1">DV Custom Sabers is the place to go for your saber needs!</div>

<div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="schedule" height="200" width="350" border="0"></a></div>

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="kotorsale.html">For Sale</a></li>
    <li><a href="buildlog.html">Build Log</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="form">
<<form action="mail.php" method="POST">

<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">

<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">


<p>Priority</p>

<select name="priority" size="1">

<option value="Low">Low</option>

<option value="Normal">Normal</option>

<option value="High">High</option>

<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>

</select>

<br />

<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />

<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">

</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$recipient = "horgantm@gmail.com<script type="text/javascript">` -- are you sure the recipient's email address is correct?

Comment: What's there in your `<script>` tags?

Comment: Hmm, seems work now, I changed the PHP a little bit, i updated the new php in the OP.

Comment: looks like once i took the java out it worked, hmm, i think my scripts were screwed up. I can just use pure html and php for this right, i do not need java?

Comment: @Terry If you entire code is in ONE file, then you need to set your action like this `action=""` - IF that's the case.

Comment: @Terry Also you have 2 `mail()` functions. Plus, try removing the first one `mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");`

Comment: @Terry You also have a stray `<` in `<<form action="mail.php" method="POST">` which should read as `<form action="mail.php" method="POST">` -  By the way, I tested your code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Terry As for *"when you click "SEND" it says thank you and redirects you to the home page"* - you can't have an `echo` AND a header redirect. It's one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is not working or do you need help with?  Please be more specific.

That being said, I see a few issues right off the bat.

Your main issue is that this line is not valid, which is probably causing the entire script to fail:

```
$recipient = "horgantm@gmail.com<script type="text/javascript"> ...
```

You must escape your double quotes or use single quotes instead.  (See how the highlighting changes?)

You also have an extra bracket in this line:

```
<<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
```

Why is there a script embedded in the recipient field anyway?

EDIT: OP changed code after my answer was posted.

Comment: can i change the size of the form in css, or only html by adding cols/rows? Id rather do css, then I can change size also for mobiel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are not redirecting anybody.

I would edit your code like this

```
    if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader))
    {
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/home.php?successfulySent");
        exit;   
    }
    else
    {
        die("Error!");
    }
```

And on the page, where you want a user to be redirected

```
    if(isset($_GET['successfulySent']))
        echo "Thank you for sendinf a message!";
```

**EDIT:**

I do not want us to be misunderstood.

I created this condition, since you wrote a statement `…and redirects you to the home page.…` regarding redirecting and you did not have it in your code.

You edited you code in the question, but you have forgotten to remove the last line (`echo "Thank You!" . " -" .…`), it is now useess, since the script either redirects a user or stops with a message `Error!`

Then a URL parameter `?successfulySent` is important for the script, where you are redirecting, to know, that this is something, that it should do.

So change `Location` url to `http://www.darthvixcustomsabers.com/index.php?successfulySent`.

And I wrote `php` extension, yes, you need to have this file as PHP file type, since you are placing there a PHP condition. In most cases, I would only rename `index.html` into `index.php`

Where to place the second condition, simply, there, where you want a message to appear.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['successfulySent'])):?>
    <div class="message" id="message-sent">
        <p>Your message has been successfuly sent to our team...</p>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: so add if(isset($_GET['successfulySent']))
    echo "Thank you for sendinf a message!"; to my index.html if I want them redirected to the home page, and edit my PHP with the other stuff you listed?

Comment: ok I got it to redirect, but i want it to say thank you once u click send, then redirect.

Comment: I read that you want a redirect, but you had not had it in your PHP code do I added it. :)

Comment: where do i put the code that you listed in your 2nd edit? Do i put that at the bottom of index.html before </html> or make a separate index.php page and paste that?

Comment: Take a look at my edit in the reply. I strived to make it clear.